# jquery hover problem on IE

Tags: jquery, hover

I have just using the jquery hover :

```
$.each(navItems, function(i){
    $(navItems[i]).hover(function(){
        $(this).find('ul:first').css({visibility: "visible",display: "none"}).show();
    },function(){
        $(this).find('ul:first').css({visibility: "hidden"});
    });
});
```

I works fine on all browser except IE. I have looking for the others code that work fine in all major browsers(include IE), normally they also using same the way i did. 
Anybody can help me to explain what i wrong? 
full code on here : http://jsfiddle.net/XrMNr/

Comment: its working for me in IE 7 and 8. Could you what exactly is not working and in what specific browser.

Comment: @iMatoria: If you can see the http://jsfiddle.net/XrMNr/, when you hover the menu navigation, and then you it should be show the drop down menu, and then you mouse move the drop down, it's disappear on IE(7, 8, 9)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All you need is this:

```
$(".NaviItem").hover(function() {
    $(this).find('ul:first').show();
}, function() {
    $(this).find('ul:first').hide();
});
```

- Select your target elements simply with `.NaviItem`. This will return all elements with class `NaviItem`
- You don't need to iterate using `each()`. In this case the `hover` handler is applied to all occurrences of `.NaviItem`
- To show/hide you don't need to set the css, just use `show()` and `hide()`, or some animation function like `fadeOut`/`fadeIn`.

Comment: @areil: I just did your way to hover on menu navigation items. But it still doesn't work on IE(7, 8, 9)

Comment: Thanks for you help. i just see jsfiddle.net/3xptU, it works fine. But i don't why when i apply this into the page it still doesn't work for me? Anyway, thanks for you help. I will try debug for myself.

Comment: check for script problems on the console (ctrl+shift+j on chrome). if you can't find anything just post another question with more details.

Comment: i have just found the probelm and fixed. That's my stupid when cc&p (copy/cut and paste).

Answer (score 0):

Why is your hover in a loop? Have you tried...

```
$('.NaviItem').hover(function(){
    $(this).find('ul:first').css({visibility: "visible", display: "none"}).show();
},function(){
    $(this).find('ul:first').css({visibility: "hidden"});
});
```

Comment: i loop menu items to register event hover for each one li.NaviItem.
i have tried your way, but it still doesn't work on IE

Comment: You just need to use the class. You don't have to loop through them.